# MVC Core App Deployment HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

I had built a MVC Core application and was publishing it to Azure and was working fine. I then had a requirement to read .xlsx files and I like to use EPPlus ot do this. Unfortunately it does not work with .Net Core so I looked to change my application to target Net461 by removed core from project.json and adding:
     "frameworks": {
      "net461": {
      }
     },
What I then found is after publishing to Azure I get the following error:
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

But if I create a new publish profile and publish as a new app it worked ok but I wish to keep using the test domain I was using and when I revert back in the future I would like to think I could do this without again creating a new web app.

Here is the full project.json after I modified to work for 461:

```
{
"userSecretsId": "aspnet-TransX-d5b24c05-d095-48a6-a88e-da78688a3d92",
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-update1",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-update1",
"EPPlus": "4.1.0"
},
"tools": {
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"frameworks": {
"net461": {
}
},
"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
},
"runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
},
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
},
"scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% -  -framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
 }
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your full `project.json` file.

Comment: Thanks have now posted it, as I stated it will publish as a new web app and load successfully so I wonder if this is more to do with Azure?